# What does "Pool is now shutting down as requested" mean when using host connection pools

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have a few streams that wake every min or so and pulling some docs from the DB and performing some actions and in the end sending messages to SNS.

The tick interval is every 1 min currently.

Every few minutes I see this error info in the log:

```
[INFO] [06/04/2020 07:50:32.326] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [default/Pool(shared->https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443)] Pool is now shutting down as requested.

[INFO] [06/04/2020 07:51:32.666] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15] [default/Pool(shared->https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443)] Pool shutting down because akka.http.host-connection-pool.idle-timeout triggered after 30 seconds.
```

What does it mean? Did someone have it before? 443 was worrying me.

Comment: This does not look like an error in any way. 443 is the port, not an error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Akka http connection pools are terminated by akka automatically if not used for a certain time (default is 30 seconds). This can be configured and set to `infinite` if needed.

The pools are re-created on next use but this takes some time, so the request initiating the creation will be "blocked" till the pool is re-created.

From [documentation.](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html)

> The time after which an idle connection pool (without pending requests) will automatically terminate itself. Set to `infinite` to completely disable idle timeouts.

The config parameter that controls it is

```
akka.http.host-connection-pool.idle-timeout
```

The log message points to the config parameter too

> Pool shutting down because akka.http.host-connection-pool.idle-timeout
>   triggered after 30 seconds.